# Image orientation changed on web after uploading from phone?

Tags: android, image-uploading, image-upload

I am able to upload successfully a picture from my phone but the orientation is getting changed when I see the profile on the laptop.

```
$upload_path = 'uploads/';
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
    if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
        header("Location: profileOne.php?error=PICTURE");
        //die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
    if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path .$user_id.".jpg")) {   

        $check=@copy($upload_path .$user_id.'.jpg', '../backend/data/profile_image/'.$user_id.'.jpg');
        if($check){
            $postdata1 = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'img'=>'data/profile_image/'.$user_id.'.jpg',
                    'type'=>'web'

                )
            );
            $opts1 = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata1
                )
            );
            $context1  = stream_context_create($opts1);
            $endPoint1='http://www.ridorama.com/backend/registration/update_profile/';
            $result1 = file_get_contents($endPoint1, false, $context1);
```

Comment: The image from the camera of device?

Comment: yeah the image i take from the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes side by device not from server because who takes the photo is device and who applies the rotation is the device... Then the problem is that you don't save rotation correctly in image stats and when you try to obtain the bytes or pass your image from bitmap class,for example, doesn't apply correctly rotation because image has in stats => rotation = 0º.

To solve correctly this problem you need to apply rotation correctly in your camera and when you camera take a photo, this one saves the camara rotation in photo stats and always that you transforms the image to bytes or in bitmap class or send photo to your server, this one respect the rotation stat from photo. Follow the below code and applies this code to camera preview class:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();

    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    }
    else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setRotation(result);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Apply this code in setCameraDisplayOrientation() method and the photo save orientation correctly and when you send the image to server, server have correctly orientation too.

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!

Comment: If you apply code right when you try to see your photo in android device, open photo details and you can see the different rotations that has the image.